# Setting up a shared (smart) folder on the top level in iOS mail

Tags: macos, ios, email

I have a local "next action" folder in the mail app on my mac. I move emails that require an action from the inboxes of my different email accounts into this folder. Also, i have asmart folder that contains flagged mails.

I would like to sync those folders with my iPad. So, the only solution I was able to think of is to create such a "next action" folder in one of my email accounts, e.g., my icloud account. However, it is very tedious on the iPad if I read emails from another inbox account and want to move them into this next action folder on my icloud account: each time i have to navigate up one level, and then navigate down into the icloud account.

Is there a way that I can link this folder to the main menu in mail on iOS? I noticed, for example, that my VIP folder (a smart folder) from my iCloud account appears there too. However, i didn't know how I achieved that. 
I would also like to set up a smart folder for flagged items that is shared between iOS and MacOs mail. How can I do that?

**So to summarize what i want to set up:**

1) A top level folder that is shared between iOS and MacOs mail

2) a top level smart folder for flagged items that is also shared

Comment: Somehow you are asking for two different things here: How to set up shared folders vs. how to add folder on same level as VIP. Can you please edit the question (and the title) to make it clearer what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, i already thought that it might be confusing. I will try to make it more clear! Ideallyi would like to set up a shared folder on the same level as VIP